# При переводе в Double ошибка "входная строка имела неверный формат"

Tags: c#, double

Из файла excel забираются данные из ячеек, ячейки, содержащие даты сначала хочу конвертировать из string в double, затем уже в datatime.
Однако в любом случае на этапе double.parse появляется эта ошибка. 
Пробовал указывать разные culture для того, чтобы дата правильно воспринималась, однако пока не помогло.

```
Excel.Application ObjWorkExcel = new Excel.Application(); //открыть эксель
        Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook = ObjWorkExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"путь", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); //открыть файл
        Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1]; //получить 1 лист

Excel.Range last = ObjWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
        Excel.Range range = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", last);

        int lastUsedRow = last.Row; // Узнаем кол-во записей (строк)
        int lastUsedColumn = last.Column;
for (int i = 1; i < last.column; i++)
        {
            // Status
            string colnum = Convert.ToString(i);
            var status = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("P" + colnum, Type.Missing).ToString();


            //Экспорт date
            //Введение объекта cell(из excel) exceldate типа double
            var exceldate = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("O" + colnum, Type.Missing).ToString();
            double exceldate_d = double.Parse(exceldate, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-ru")); //ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ

            var date = DateTime.FromOADate(exceldate_d).ToString("ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));//перевод в datetime
```

В Excel даты содержаться в формате 29.03.2018, т.е. culture ru-ru, однако почему-то все равное не воспринимается.
Для проверки себя пытался также преобразовать конкретную дату, взятую не из excel

```
string b = "29.03.2018";
double exceldate_d = double.Parse(b, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-ru"));
```

В результате была та же ошибка. Где не прав в преобразовании в double? Подскажите товарищи!

Comment: А какой ожидается результат? Не совсем ясно почему дату нужно преобразовать в число.

Comment: Предполагается, что мы сможем забрать дату из ячейки эксель (там она 29.03.2018) и  конвертировать так, чтобы в конце получилась переменная string формата "29MAR18"

Comment: @IgorNosov, так а зачем в число преобразовывать?

Comment: Так как после получения даты из эксель в переменную типа string. Нужно привести ее к другому виду даты, это можно сделать через Datetime. Но как раз datetime ругается на то, что не может конвертировать переменную типа string. Потому получился промежуточный шаг с double. Допускаю что есть возможно как то это сделать и без double, но я не знаю как

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно, зачем вы пытаетесь парсить в double. Если вам нужен DateTime, то используйте следующее: DateTime.Parse("29.03.2018",new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-Ru")

Comment: Так я пробовал делать изначально. Т.к. мы парсим не конкретную дату "29.03.2018", а содержимое ячейки excel (ObjWorkSheet), то datetime в любом случае будет ругаться.

Comment: На что ругается DateTime и какой тип получаемых из ячейки данных?

Comment: Когда получаем данные из ячейки эксель, то присваиваем этой переменной тип string. Если оставить только var exceldate = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("O" + colnum, Type.Missing).ToString();  var date = DateTime.FromOADate(exceldate).ToString("ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));   То переменная exceldate подчеркивается с ошибкой "не удается преобразовать string в double".

Comment: Попробуете сделать так:          
            var exceldate = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("O" + colnum, Type.Missing).ToString();

            var date = DateTime.Parse(exceldate ,new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-Ru").ToString("ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));

Comment: Что из себя представляет значение exceldate?

Comment: К сожалению к Tostring здесь нельзя приложить такие аргументы ToString("ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us")), тоже уже пробовал.

Comment: Exceldate, переменная типа string и  должна содержать данные из эксель файла, из ячейки O1, O2 итд по циклу. В колонке O эксель файла содержаться даты в виде 29.03.2018

Comment: А можно пример того, что приходит в exeldate?

Comment: Ох, проблема оказалась выше преобразования в datetime. Спасибо что навели на мысль! В переменную exceldate пишется значение "System.__ComObject". Надо поработать над выгрузкой значений из excel